# Android HttpUrlConnection navigate after login

Tags: java, android, http, url, networking

I am building an app that uses the HttpUrlConnection to request a POST method sending the username and password to their respective fields on a website(this part works fine). After that, as a logged in member, I want to navigate to a new URL which will show me profile Info for example, ideally here I would use the GET reaquest. But here is the problem: to make the GET request I need to make a new HttpUrlConnection to the new URL therefore I will loose my login status.

Can I save my login cookies to use on the next connection? Will that even work? Or is there a way to navigate to a different URL with the same HttpUrlConnection?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I had to share the cookies between the two, luckily all I had to do was to declare a CookieManager.

```
java.net.CookieManager cookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```